# Objective-C strange appearance in debugger after stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: objective-c, debugging, str-replace, lldb

I´m on Mac OS X and Xcode 4.5.2 
When executing these lines:

```
NSString *asSrcFileName = @"chromebar.png"
NSString *asSrcExtName  = @".png"
NSString *asTempName    = [asSrcFileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:asSrcExtName withString:@""];
```

I get a strange view of my variables in the debugger. See rectangle:
[image]
I expected asTmp to be @"chromebar" after line three. 
I´ve been using **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** pretty often so far and have no idea what´s wrong. Somehow it looks like there is a unicode issue.

Anyone out there to shed some light on me?

Comment: +1 for a clear and a well-formatted question.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with memory management.

Comment: You have used NSString *asTempName but why debugger is showing asSrcTempName?

Comment: That is OK. I shortened the variable name for this message. Sorry I missed to correct that.
@H2CO3: is that possible? This is a very small project so far with 400 lines. And NSLog(@"asTargetFileName: %@",asTargetFileName); returns the proper result.

Comment: @RonaldHofmann Uh, ouch... lldb bug, maybe?

Comment: I observed the same behaviour of the debugger recently but never had any related issue regarding the actual execution of the code. I guess it is a lldb (that is the debugger) error on the visualisation only. Just don't worry about.

Comment: Yes, the same here. The actual results are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you inspecting `asSrcTempName` after the variable has been initialized (the green line showing the current execution point is below the initialization)?

Otherwise it's probably only uninitialized memory and lldb is showing garbage from a previous run.

I could not reproduce your problem in Xcode 4.5.1.

Comment: After switching the debugger to GDB I don´t have that problem anymore. Thanks all the guys for helpful answers.